# Creating a table for time series analysis including counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got a dataframe on which I would like to perform some analysis. An easy example of what I would like to achieve is, having the dataframe:

```
data = ['2017-02-13', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-16']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['date'])
```

I would like to create a new dataframe from this. The new dataframe should contain 2 columns, the entire date span. So it should also include 2017-02-14 and the number of times each date appears in the original data.

I managed to construct a dataframe that includes all the dates as so:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dateRange = pd.date_range(start = dates.min(), end = dates.max()).tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = datumRange, columns = ['datum'])
```

My question is, how would I add the counts of each date from df to df 2? I've been messing around trying to write my own functions but have not managed to achieve it. I am assuming this needs to be done more often and that I am thinking to difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2['counts'] = df2['datum'].map(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Looks good as a starter but return a float instead of an integer.

Comment: add `.astype(int)` to the end